# Windows 8.1 and totally denied access to all users and administrators

Tags: windows, user-management, access-control

I lost control over one whole disc. I called `icacls` and denied all access on `g:\` to `Everyone`. But then - every call of `icacls` fails with the access denied message. Neither owner nor any administrator is able to repair these rights, the data are lost for Windows. I can just take ownership, but then nothing. I'm astound. There is no superuser like root in Linux? Is it ever possible to rescue such error-states in Win 8.1? Really can I irrecoverably revoke me own rights for ever?

Comment: Try to boot your computer with a linux livecd, maybe you can access your data (if it weren't encrypted).

Comment: I know, but I wanna know, if there is some standard solution, not a workaround. Of course, I haven't lost my data in fact. But let say, that it can happen: somebody call me, that he had done this with some encrypted medium. Then some standard (or _system_) solution is the only way to solve it. And I say: _sorry, sir, I cannot help you, because anybody including me doesn't know how._ It's strange, but that's the current status-quo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate your problem. I created a 1GB VHD, attached it as drive `G:`, set permissions on the drive "Everyone -> Deny Full Access". I get the same "Access Denied" error.

Then I open the Drive's properties, Security Tab, Advanced..., change Owner to myself. Once the dialog is closed and re-opened (per the message displayed) I can see and change permissions on the drive.

Comment: In the evening I was struggling again and solved my problem this way too. I took ownership as one of local admins and then saw everyone's rights, granted them, confirmed several warnings and errors and then was able to access data again. Strange, however it is a system solution.